# Django - operate on database within transaction.atomic block after raising error

Tags: django, exception, transactions, atomic

I would like to perform an action on my database within a transaction.atomic() block, even in the event that an error is raised. Here is some sample code to demonstrate my issue:

**Sample code**

```
# Outer try block
try:

    # Enclose in atomic transaction for database rollbacks
    with transaction.atomic():

        # If this line fails, all database updates within the outer try: block should be rolled back
        u = UU.create(email='test@test.com')

        # Inner try block
        try:
            cc = CC.objects.get(id=1)
            perform_action(cc)

        # If this exception triggers, the 'cc' object should be deleted, but all other database updates within the outer try: block should be rolled back
        except:
            cc.delete()
            raise

        # If this line fails, all database updates within the outer try: block should be rolled back
        u = UU.create(email='test@test.com')

# If any exception triggers, this error should be printed
except:
    print("Error occured.")
```

If an error occurs in my inner `try:` block, I want the `cc` object to be deleted, but all other database transactions within the outer `try:` block to be rolled back. However, as the code stands now, the `cc.delete()` transaction will be rolled back if any error occurs within the inner `try:` block.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't keep just one part of a database transaction, and you can't keep an inner transaction while rolling back the outer transaction.

Instead, you can signal that specific error state with a custom exception, and then do your additional processing when you catch it, after the rollback. Something like:

```
class BadCCException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, badid):
        super().__init__()
        self.badid = badid

try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        u = UU.create(email='test@test.com')

        try:
            cc = CC.objects.get(id=1)
            perform_action(cc)
        except Exception as e:
            raise BadCCException(1) from e

        u = UU.create(email='test@test.com')
except BadCCException as e:
    CC.objects.filter(id=e.badid).delete()
    print("Error occured.")
except:
    print("Error occured.")
```

Comment: Brilliant - this will work great. Thanks much for your help!